# List of Lists in C# - Combining multiple data types into a master list?

Tags: c#, nested-lists

I'm attempting to combine 11 different data types into a single list that I can add to and delete from, as well as search for particular values.  These data types range involve bool, string, int and double.

The goal is to add updated values to this master list as they come in every minute.  For example... at 5:45 pm, 11 new values would be captured from a system.  Those 11 values, if passing if/else if challenges, would be added to the master list.  These 11 values would be:

- Slot 1 - Time[0].ToString("HH:mm"); (shown as an example)
- Slot 2 - (data type double)
- Slot 3 - (data type double)
- Slot 4 - (data type double)
- Slot 5 - (data type double)
- Slot 6 - (data type double)
- Slot 7 - (data type double)
- Slot 8 - (data type double)
- Slot 9 - (data type bool)
- Slot 10 - (data type string)
- Slot 11 - (data type double)

If the incoming data didn't pass the if/else if challenges, then the corresponding list would be reset with all existing data removed from the list.

I've gone through different questions here and also via a couple of web searches, but I'm either not understanding how to declare the list or list structures properly, if I should be using classes or arrays, etc.

Comment: Why don't you use a [`DataTable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.aspx) instead?

Comment: Why can't you make a tuple-class out of the 11 slots, and then have a list of objects of that class?

Comment: You almost certainly need a `class` to hold your data. What does this information represent? Does, say, `Slot 5` always represent the same "thing" (even if the values may be different)?

Comment: @AdamRobinson - To answer your question, yes, Slot 5 would always have a double value in it, though the value would change.  To follow up, would a class allow me the same find/add/remove functionality as a list would?  Or is a class simply a container for the above data?

Comment: @Spiderbird Are you going to be adding additional fields of information to track, at runtime, or are you only ever adding information in groups based on the provided schema?

Comment: @cdhowie - I'm not sure that would work.  From what I read here (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple.aspx), a tuple-class would only allow for a single entry of different data to be added to it.  I'm looking to potentially add multiple entries as long as certain criteria is met.  Did I reference the wrong article on tuple-classes?

Comment: @Servy - It would be the latter (only adding information in groups based on the provided schema).  The incoming data would be tested to meet established criteria.  If it passes, it's ideally added to the class/datatable/master list.  Note:  The criteria for incoming data would involve referencing previously saved data in the class/datatable/master list, if available.

Comment: I'm not talking about "the `Tuple` class," I am talking about the concept of "tuple": an ordered list of elements.  In this case, a class you will define, having 11 properties.

Comment: @Spiderbird In that case, you most certainly want to create a new class, rather than using a `List` or some other type of data structure.

Comment: @Servy - Got it.  I'll go in that direction and persue a class structure then.  Thanks again for your time and help!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Those 11 slots you've lists seem to be describing a `class`.  You should create a class that has 11 properties, one for each of your slots.  It should have the appropriate data type, as well as a meaningful name (don't just call it slot1, slot2).

That class should have an IsValid method, because it seems that you need to be able to validate a unit of data for this class.

You can then have a collection (Possibly a `List`, although you haven't told us enough about how you're using it to know if it's the best fit) of those classes that you can add to (if valid), remove from, and search.

Comment: Hi Servy, to clarify, I would ideally collect the incoming data, check to see if certain 'slots' have the right data in them (ex: Slot 5 is >= 500), and if true, add all incoming data to each of the 11 slots, creating a new set for that minute of the day (ex: 5:30 pm).  At 5:31 pm, the process begins again.  If the criteria mentioned above passes, a new set for that minute of the day is added to the 'collection' (for 5:31 pm).  Slot 1 hypothetically would hold a ToString representation of the time the data was collected.  Does that help?

Comment: @Spiderbird It doesn't change anything in my answer, nor does it tell me enough to add anything to it either.

Comment: Btw Servy, thanks for taking the time to write out an answer.  I didn't give thanks the first time around.

Comment: @Spiderbird You don't need to (not that you *can't*); that's the way the site is designed.  If you feel an answer was helpful, then upvote it.  That is the generally accepted way to "give thanks" to a good answer.

Answer (score 5):

Just use this:

```
List<IList> yourList = new List<IList>(){
    //you'll able to add different types of list there
}
//dont forget to use this:
using System.Collections
```

or

```
List<System.Collections.IList> yourList = new List<System.Collections.IList>(){
    //you'll able to add different types of list there
}
```

Tested and worked :D

Answer (score 1):

There is more than 1 possibility and that is your choice depending on the characteristics of your problem. You could create an `Object` to represent that as mentioned on previous posts or even use a `DataTable` where your slots would be the columns and, if your "if/else if challenges" - as you called - passes, it would create a new row.

See the reference below:

[System.Data.DataTable Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.aspx)

Kind Regards, 
Herbert WaLL

Comment: Hi xWaLL - Thanks for that answer!  I'm going to look into both Classes and DataTables as a possible solution.  From the example you gave at MSDN, it seems to involve more code up front to construct the DataTable than a Class per se.  Is there an advantage with going with a DataTable versus a Class for the above problem IYO?

Comment: Hi @SpiderBird, I do not see any advantage from using DataTable versus Class for that problem, it's an option. DataTables are really easy to deal with NULL values and has search, delete and update mechanisms in place. However, these "features" are not something that you would not be able to create by implementing them on your own class.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<object> Slots = new List<object>();

To Add Slot:
Slots.Add((double)23.45);
```

Answer (score -1):

Although I suggest creating a class to hold your data, e.g.

```
public class SlotData
{
    public DateTime Slot1 { get; set; }
    public Double Slot2 { get; set; }
    public Double Slot3 { get; set; }
    public Double Slot4 { get; set; }
    public Double Slot5 { get; set; }
    public Double Slot6 { get; set; }
    public Double Slot7 { get; set; }
    public Double Slot8 { get; set; }
    public Boolean Slot9 { get; set; }
    public String Slot10 { get; set; }
    public Double Slot11 { get; set; }
}
```

you could also get away with a List of objects as long as you make sure to check the type prior to using the data.

```
List<object> SlotData = new List<object>();

if (SlotData[0] != null && SlotData[0] is DateTime)
{
  Do something
}
```

Comment: Hi Mark.. thanks for your answer!  One question though.. would you lean more towards your first answer (class) or your second answer (list of objects) if I'm eventually going to search/add/modify data in those constructs?  Is one option easier than the other in terms of the amount of code I would potentially have to write?

Comment: If your goal is maintainability, use option 1 (with names more appropriate than Slot1, Slot2, etc.)

Comment: If your goal is quick and dirty, throw-away-code (which is hardly ever the case), then go with option 2.

Comment: I hate to downvote this (as it does recommend the proper approach), but there is zero reason to use a list of objects to represent something that has a structure.

Comment: @Mark Given that option two is harder to write, will take longer, be less likely to work (meaning more time spent debugging/fixing/maintaining/rewriting) that's not really true at all.  It would be appropriate if there isn't a fixed number of well defined pieces of data.  If an 'object' is represented by some unknown number of fields (not true here) then you can't just have properties to represent them all.

Answer (score -1):

The solution should be use List of objects List.
So there is not problem to store any value to list.
And when you want to get some value from list, you can cast it as you need.

Or other better solution is to make class which will contain member with type object and second member which will be the type of value stored in object member.
See example:

```
    // class for storing values
    public class SlotItem
    {

        public object Val { get; private set; }
        public Type ValType { get; private set; }

        public SlotItem(object o, Type valType)
        {
            Val = o;
            ValType = valType;
        }
    }



    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // store values to List
        List<SlotItem> list = new List<SlotItem>();
        list.Add(new SlotItem("sometext", typeof(String))); // store text
        list.Add(new SlotItem(100, typeof(Int32)));         // store number

        // read values from List
        foreach (SlotItem slot in list)
        {
            var val = Convert.ChangeType(slot.Val, slot.ValType);
            Response.Write(val);
        }
    }
```